# SELECT with LIMIT and OFFSET in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a site develop in Codeigniter, and in my model I have a function like this:

```
public function nationList($limit = null, $start = null)
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('language') == "it") {
        $this->db->select('nation.id, nation.name_it as name');
    }
    if ($this->session->userdata('language') == "en") {
        $this->db->select('nation.id, nation.name_en as name');
    }
    $this->db->from('nation');
    $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $nation = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        array_push($nation, $row);
    }
    return $nation;     
}
```

And if into my controller I call the function without limit and start doesn't return result like this:

```
$data["nationlist"] = $this->Nation_model->nationList();
```

Instead if I set limit and start works!
If limit and start are null, Why doesn't return result? I don't want to make a second function or a control if limit and start are null.
How can I solve this when limit and start are null without a control or a second function to make useful the code and more efficient?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without an `if` statement.

Comment: ok... I hoped to do this without a control.. but why the query doesn't return something when limit and start are nulla? @Mischa

Comment: You'd have to look at the source code for CodeIgniter, but I presume `$this->db->limit(null, null);` generates `LIMIT 0,0` in MySQL, which returns zero database rows.

Comment: understand... I'm thinking that with a 'null' value the limit isn't considered by the query

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1203) `$this->db->limit(null, null);` should return `LIMIT 1`. Anyway, just add an `if` ;-)

Comment: ok add an if thanks for the explanation I haven't found this information @Mischa

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri If you really don't want to use an `if` statement in your code, although it seems the most efficient, you could extend the DB class and change the behaviour of `limit` there so that it can accept and process `null` values. Then in your controller/model you will not need to worry about the `if` statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this...

```
function nationList($limit=null, $start=null) {
    if ($this->session->userdata('language') == "it") {
        $this->db->select('nation.id, nation.name_it as name');
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('language') == "en") {
        $this->db->select('nation.id, nation.name_en as name');
    }

    $this->db->from('nation');
    $this->db->order_by("name", "asc");

    if ($limit != '' && $start != '') {
       $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    }
    $query  = $this->db->get();

    $nation = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        array_push($nation, $row);
    }

    return $nation;     
}
```

Comment: ok with control I know how to do but I want to know why the query doesn't return the query and to solve It without a control if is possible read the question is specified

Answer (score 14):

For further visitors:

```
// Executes: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
// get([$table = ''[, $limit = NULL[, $offset = NULL]]])
$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);

// get_where sample, 
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), 10, 20);

// Produces: LIMIT 10
$this->db->limit(10);  

// Produces: LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
// limit($value[, $offset = 0])
$this->db->limit(10, 20);
```

Comment: the ->db->limit(10) call should be first before ->get_where() ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of CI you were using back in 2013, but I am using CI3 and I just tested with two `null` parameters passed to `limit()` and there was no `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` in the rendered query (I checked by using `get_compiled_select()`).

This means that -- assuming your have correctly posted your coding attempt -- you don't need to change anything (or at least the old issue is no longer a CI issue).

If this was my project, this is how I would write the method to return an indexed array of objects or an empty array if there are no qualifying rows in the result set.

```
function nationList($limit = null, $start = null) {
    // assuming the language value is sanitized/validated/whitelisted
    return $this->db
        ->select('nation.id, nation.name_' . $this->session->userdata('language') . ' AS name')
        ->from('nation')
        ->order_by("name")
        ->limit($limit, $start)
        ->get()
        ->result();
}
```

These refinements remove unnecessary syntax, conditions, and the redundant loop.

For reference, here is the CI core code:

```
/**
 * LIMIT
 *
 * @param   int $value  LIMIT value
 * @param   int $offset OFFSET value
 * @return  CI_DB_query_builder
 */
public function limit($value, $offset = 0)
{
    is_null($value) OR $this->qb_limit = (int) $value;
    empty($offset) OR $this->qb_offset = (int) $offset;

    return $this;
}
```

So the `$this->qb_limit` and `$this->qb_offset` class objects are not updated because `null` evaluates as `true` when fed to `is_null()` or `empty()`.